# unable to navigate html files in eclipse using tomcat server

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am using a Eclipse Juno with Tomcat 7.
After creating a java dynamic web project, i added a folder `home` folder in `WebContent` directory. Inside home folder i added `address.jsp` and `h1.html`.
What i was trying to do is call/link `h1.html` from `address.jsp`. I have written following code in `address.jsp` to do so:

`<a href="h1.html">Go to h1</a>`. But I am getting 404 error each time...

However when I added 1 more folder `home2` in `WebContent` and inside home2 i added `h2.html` and then I finally change my code in `address.jsp` as:

`<a href="home2/h2.html">Go to home2/h2</a>`. Now in this case I am not getting any error and h2.html is displaying properly. I wanted to know why I am not able to access html file from same directory.

Following is the hierarchy...

```
-------WebContent---------->
    ----------home----->
            ---address.jsp
            ---h1.html
    ----------home2----->
            ---h2.html
```

Comment: are u sure ur address.jsp is inside ur home folder?or is it in webcontent?i.e home folder and address.jsp are under webcontent

Comment: could you post the link in the address bar when you open that link.

Comment: @santino'sonny'corleone my `address.jsp` and `h1.html` files are inside `home` folder and `home` folder is ultimately inside main `webcontent` folder. And I have made `address.jsp` as my welcome file in Deployment-Descriptor `web.xml`. `address.jsp` file is displayed OK but when i call `h1.html` from `address.jsp` using `<a href="h1.html">Go to h1</a>` it causes 404 error.

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU Following is the link in address bar when I use `<a href="h1.html">Go to h1</a>` code from `address.jsp`    `http://localhost:5353/DynaWebProject/h1.html`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... Instead of using `<a href="h1.html">Go to h1</a>`, I had to use `<a href="home/h1.html">Go to h1</a>`. I'm surprise, why am i have to mention the current directory, (in this case its `home`) even when I'm already in that directory. I think it only happens when we're creating web pages in `Eclipse` environment using `Tomcat` because there is no such requirement, if we are simply creating pages in some other editor like notepad or notepad++ in same folder, without using tomcat server.